# how to deploy gdata-objectivec-client library in xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, gdata, cross-reference

I want to create an application that support Youtube API. I use this tutorial for create cross-references project

**http://mischneider.net/blog/?s=gdata**

But this tutorial deploy my project only in XCode 3. My questions - how do I connect GData in XCode 4

Thanks all!

*I will be happy with any answers for my questions.*

Comment: http://mischneider.net/blog/?s=gdata - this tutorial shows very well how to connect the project in xcode 3 but i don't know how do it in XCode 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prepared a step-by-step tutorial of GData deployment in Xcode 4.

http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/

Hope it helps :)